# Push notification from MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, autobahn, autobahnws

I am having my database created in MYSQL and a WebSocket application(Autobahn Wamp WebSocket v1) created in Python.
I have an application which makes entries in my database.

My requirement is that I need to create a trigger in MYSQL which would notify my Python WebSocket application(Autobahn Wamp WebSocket v1) when data gets inserted in my database.

I would like to know whether it is possible to achieve the above mentioned functionality or not, and if yes how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a pretty full example with MySQL code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474012/invoke-pusher-when-mysql-has-changed

Comment: The MySQL data can be inserted by others than your Web app ?

Comment: Yes the MYSQL data is inserted by others. Not by my app...

Comment: PostgreSQL allows you to do this via a TRIGGER and NOTIFY : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-notify.html. I don't whether MySQL has similar functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The [python-mysql-replication](https://github.com/noplay/python-mysql-replication) project maybe interesting. It allows you to receive event like insert, update, delete with their datas from your application

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use pubsubsql which is Mysql push notification service.
The link is as follows :
https://github.com/pubsubsql

Comment: This project lost their .com domain to squatters. I replaced it with GitHub link