# How to execute Python function when value in SQL table changes?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, raspberry-pi

I am having trouble finding this answer anywhere on the internet. I want to be able to monitor a row in a MySQL table for changes and when this occurs, run a Python function. This Python function I want to run has nothing to do with MySQL; it just enables a pin on a Raspberry Pi. I have tried looking into SQLAlchemy; however, I can't tell if it is a trigger or a data mapping. Is something like this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use `pull` instead of `push`? if this is a specific row, just query it for changes every X minutes/seconds. If these could be many rows, create a `flag` table and add `UPDATE` triggers to alter the flag there, and your python application will `poll` for changes and set the flag back...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a loop which keeps checking the value of that row in MySQL table,the moment the value changes, call the function you want to execute.
you can also refer to [python: how to get notifications for mysql database changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771925/python-how-to-get-notifications-for-mysql-database-changes)

Comment: It sounds like UDF is the only way to do it. I just don't really want to make a loop because it seems like it could really burden the database with overhead. I was hoping to make it check more intelligently. My inspiration is kinda like Dropbox. It only syncs when it gets changes.

Comment: If all you are doing is `select my_column from my_table where ...` you're not really burdening the DB

Comment: Really? If that is true, this is a simple solution.

Comment: user2112825 is right, because MySQL has been designed to handle a large number of operations simultaneously, this would hardly affect the functioning of your database.

Answer (score 4):

What about a cron job instead of create a loop? I think it's a bit nicer.