# How to receive automatic notifications about changes in tables?

Tags: python, postgresql, events, triggers, listener

*What I am using*: **PostgreSQL** and **Python**. *I am using Python to access PostgreSQL*

*What I need*: Receive a automatic notification, on Python, if anyone records something on a specific table on database.

I think that it is possible using a routine that go to that table, over some interval, and check changes. But it **requires a loop** and I would like something like an a **assynchronous way**.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking for updates due to changes of data IN a table (i.e. insert, update, delete), or updates due to changes to the construction of a table (i.e. alter table)?

Comment: Insert Update Delete.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

donmage is quite right - `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` are what you want. You'll still need a polling loop, but it's very lightweight, and won't cause detectable server load.

If you want `psycopg2` to trigger callbacks at *any time* in your program, you can do this by spawning a thread and having that thread execute the polling loop.  Check to see whether psycopg2 enforces thread-safe connection access; if it doesn't, you'll need to do your own locking so that your polling loop only runs when the connection is idle, and no other queries interrupt a polling cycle.  Or you can just use a second connection for your event polling.

Either way, when the background thread that's polling for notify events receives one, it can invoke a Python callback function supplied by your main program, which might modify data structures / variables shared by the rest of the program. Beware, if you do this, that it can quickly become a nightmare to maintain.

If you take that approach, I strongly suggest using the `multithreading` / `multiprocessing` modules. They will make your life massively easier, providing simple ways to exchange data between threads, and limiting modifications made by the listening thread to simple and well-controlled locations.

If using threads instead of processes, it is important to understand that in cPython (i.e. "normal Python") you can't have a true callback interrupt, because only one thread may be executing in cPython at once. Read about the "global interpreter lock" (GIL) to understand more about this. Because of this limitation (and the easier, safer nature of shared-nothing by default concurrency) I often prefer multiprocessing to multithreading.

Comment: Who is donmage?

Answer (score 17):

The commands you are looking for are probably [LISTEN/NOTIFY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-notify.html).

If you are using psycopg, check out the section [Asynchronous Notifications](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/async.html#asynchronous-notifications).

[This does require polling though.]

Comment: While polling is required, it's only extremely lightweight polling - you can send an empty command, e.g. `curs.execute("")`, to tickle the connection. If you're not using SSL there's actually no reason psycopg2 can't check for new readable data on the socket and do this without polling at all, but it might not support that.

Comment: @CraigRinger psycopg2 supports this, its notify/listen [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#asynchronous-notifications) contains an example that uses `select.select([conn],[],[],5)`. Of course you can even use an infinite timeout via `select.select([conn], [], [])` and/or alternatively poll the connection file-descriptor via the poll/epoll syscalls. So polling like this isn't busy-polling nor periodically polling, but sleeping until a notification arrives from the server.

Comment: @maxschlepzig You'll need to poll if you're on a SSL/TLS conn IIRC

Comment: @CraigRinger It [sounds](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/24912.1260464796%40sss.pgh.pa.us) [like](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4B2267A9.1080302%40postnewspapers.com.au) that might be an artifact when testing it with just `psql` - the only issue with SSL/TLS that would sound plausible is that your poll/select registered file descriptor might get ready for read too often for some unrelated TLS traffic  - but this shouldn't lead to your client missing notifications. I guess the only way to settle this is to come up with a minimal reproducing - say - python/psycopg2 example.

Comment: @CraigRinger ok, I've tested this with psycopg3 over TLS 1.3 between two Fedora 37 hosts (postgresql-14.3-8.fc37.x86_64), using a minimal psycopg listen snippet straight out of its documentation and everything works as expected. Using strace on the client I can verify that indeed it isn't periodically polling, but sleeping inside `epoll_wait()` (with a 100 s timeout) right until the notification comes. Also, a tcpdump verifies that the connection indeed is TLS encrypted.

Comment: @maxschlepzig Thanks for testing. I misremembered. I thought the limitation with ssl/tls was server-side. It's actually a limitation in the PgJDBC driver and its SSL socket client. So this issue doesn't apply on non-Java clients, I was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a trigger:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/A_Brief_Real-world_Trigger_Example

Comment: Not just a trigger. I need something more, for Python, when the trigger is fired I can call a function, for example, but **inside Python**.

Comment: You can write triggers in python you know. Not sure that's what you need. But a trigger and a notify / listen setup seems like what you really want.