# Using PostgreSQL notifications to avoid complicating the project infrastructure

Tags: django, postgresql, asynchronous, websocket, push-notification

I want to broadcast user notifications using WebSockets, and send them using the PostgreSQL NOTIFY syntax.

I also want to avoid introducing another server into the solution - be it Redis, RabbitMQ, etc.

**Is this feasible? Are there issues with asynchronous LISTEN in PostgreSQL?**

Comment: Well, what's going to `LISTEN` on the socket? PostgreSQL doesn't support WebSockets connections directly, so you'll need something to handle the PostgreSQL protocol.

Comment: Of course - that would be a `gevent-socketio` / `tornadio` server.

Comment: OK, so you really just need a broker that keeps the PostgreSQL protocol (libpq / psycopg2 / PgJDBC / Pg gem / node-postgres / whatever) connections to PostgreSQL and LISTENs on them, polling for new data to read on the socket. Exact process depends on the client driver being used. That server then sends websockets messages to the client.

Comment: BTW, the "polling" involved is usually to send an empty query, i.e. execute the statement `""`. If you're using a non-SSL connection some client drivers support purely local non-blocking polling where there's no server traffic too. None of them AFAIK support asynchronous callback functions - not technically impossible, just nobody's implemented it that I know of.

Comment: @CraigRinger This is incorrect. A postgres client worth its money such as psycopg doesn't periodically send an empty query when polling new notifications! It also doesn't matter whether the client is connected via SSL/TLS or not! For example psycopg simply sleeps in an `epoll_wait` system call when waiting for new notifications. [See also my replies to a similar comment of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117431/how-to-receive-automatic-notifications-about-changes-in-tables/21120762?noredirect=1#comment133875360_21120762).

Comment: @maxschlepzig Interesting. That must be a PgJDBC-specific issue then. My mistake. It's been quite a while since I worked on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is feasible. The postgresql NOTIFY/LISTEN feature allows for efficient notification of clients since clients don't have to periodically poll a table for changes or something like that. Instead, it's sufficient to register the DB connection's file descriptor with epoll/poll/select (for read readiness), such that the process is able to sleep until the next notification in case it doesn't have something better to do.

Packages like [psycopg do this](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/async.html#asynchronous-notifications) under the hood. Minimal psycopg3 example:

```
import psycopg
db = psycopg.connect('dbname=somedb ...', autocommit=True)
db.execute('LISTEN testchannel')
xs = db.notifies()
for x in xs:
    print(x)
```

---

There are some technical limits to payload size and server side buffering, but they seem to be hard to exceed in practice. See the [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) for details:

> payload [..] In the default configuration it must be shorter than 8000 bytes. (If binary data or large amounts of information need to be communicated, it's best to put it in a database table and send the key of the record.)

> There is a queue that holds notifications that have been sent but not yet processed by all listening sessions. If this queue becomes full, transactions calling NOTIFY will fail at commit. The queue is quite large (8GB in a standard installation) and should be sufficiently sized for almost every use case. However, no cleanup can take place if a session executes LISTEN and then enters a transaction for a very long time.