# I want mysql signal to my java code as soon as something adds

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table in database and I want mysql signal to my java code as soon as something adds to database. How can I make mysql understood to do that?

I do not really know where to start?

Comment: Someone needs their upvoting privilege revoked.

Comment: mysql and java are 2 totally different things.  Java could be a web app, a standalone app

Comment: I know but I think they are related somehow I just want to know where to start?

Comment: Is there this capability available in mysql?

Comment: you don't know where to start because you shouldn't.  bad design.

Comment: maybe I explained badly ,Lets explain my scenario: I have a map and I crawl some locations and store them on database I want to show the location on the map as soon as they added to database so how can I understand the new rows is added?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771925/python-how-to-get-notifications-for-mysql-database-changes solution here

Comment: The idea is to use Udf to perform network notifications

Answer (score 1):

no, this isn't what you want.

apps shouldn't be sharing a database this way.

a better design would be to put a data service in front of it to manage data access.

Comment: Do you think he understand what you are saying?

Comment: no, i don't think he understands what he wants, either.

Comment: Lets explain my scenario: I have a map and I crawl some locations and store them on database I want to show the location on the map as soon as they added to database so how can I understand the new rows is added?

Comment: the thing storing to the database should be signalling to the client that it should update.  thinking that the database should be responsible suggests that you don't understand this problem.

Comment: So can you tell who is responsible for that ? because I dont have access to crawler all I can have access is database and my part which is user interface so I think there should be some way to get signal from database when new row is added!

Comment: i think the thing that owns and initiates the crawler should be writing to the database.  you have ui; there's a database.  classic layering says there is a controller in the middle.  that's what i'm talking about.

Comment: I know you are right but the problem is that the crawler is run on a server and this is a very big project I dont have access  to crawler the only part that I have access is database and UI so if any method is in the database that when new row is added it can signal that is great but apparently there is no such a thing

Comment: I do not know how you got my level of smartness but thanks for answering